# Oracle error ORA-00971

Tags: sql, database, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

I'm getting an error when running the following SQL against oracle 10g (10.2.0.1.0):

```
UPDATE fx_datumvcompgeneric AS c
   SET mp =  (SELECT p.mp
                FROM fx_propertyattrsingletscomp AS p
               WHERE c.var_container = p.id
             )
 WHERE c.mp IS NULL
```

The error is: `ORA-00971: missing SET keyword`

We're doing this through JDBC, the top of the exception stack is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

  oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:957)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1170)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1623)
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1588)
  org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:225)
  org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:225)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's awesome when answers concur so eaily!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of both AS keywords - Oracle doesn't like them here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't alias a table with `AS` in an update

Answer (score 1):

Just remove AS: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems053.htm